# Kernel address space layout

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

Userland address space is well documented, which includes segments like heap, stack, .text, .bss, etc. But there is not enough documentation on kernel address space. Since certain virtual address is used in kernel space, I am wondering how kernel space is structured?

PS: I heard there is a kernel stack segment, but can not find a more systematic introduction on the kernel address space.

The platform of interest is x86_64 and Linux 3-*

Comment: of coz I am coding in kernel...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be a huge doc to start, but I think it's worth the time you'll need to read it : Have look on the ["Linux-Insides"](https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/) doc, more precisely the [Memory Management](https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/blob/master/mm/README.md) part.
You can also read it through [Gitbooks](http://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/mm/index.html)

Have fun.